# how to unzip .zip file in codeigniter 4 (PHP)

Tags: php, zip, extract, php-ziparchive

I am trying to extract zip file in codeigniter 4... I have the code below

```
    $file_name =  session()->get('file_name');
        
        // Zip file name
    $filename = "/public/$file_name";

    $zip = new \ZipArchive;
    
    $res = $zip->open($filename);
    
    if ($res === true) {

 // Unzip path
        $path = "/public";

        // Extract file
        $zip->extractTo($path);
        $zip->close();

        return 'Site Updated Successfully';
        
    } else {
        
        return "failed to update $filename!";
        
    }
        }
```

but I get this result: return "failed to update $filename!";

Please can someone help me fix the issue with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing specifically to do with Codeigniter.  It's just using PHP and ZipArchive.  The code looks OK - be sure the file is really in the `/public/` directory and that it is a zip archive.  The PHP site has examples that are like `$zip = new ZipArchive;` (without the \ char);  maybe try that.